# CW post revisions should alert greatest contributor

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, revisions-list, alerts

Community wiki posts do not show the original poster's avatar, and if someone else has contributed more to the post than the OP, it is now attributed to that person, with a percentage displayed that approximates how much of the post was generated/edited by them.

Right now only the OP is alerted to revisions.

Given that someone else has now invested enough time in the post to be considered the greatest contributor for it, shouldn't we also alert them to revisions?

Comment: Potential implementation difficulty: If I "own" 40% of a post, and someone comes along and edits 50% of it, then the system performs an alert - but the greatest contributor has now changed to the new person.  The system would have to account for this and alert the greatest editor prior to the edit, rather than simply the greatest editor at the end of the edit. Not knowing how the system performs the revision alert, I don't know if this is an easy problem or not, but it wouldn't be helpful to alert the new editor that they just edited the CW post...